# Search a text document for a line - JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, authentication

I am trying to make a login screen that can read the usernames and passwords from a text file. I have already built the registration page which outputs the username and password to a file by executing the following:

```
try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream)) {
            try {
              out.write(username + " " + password);
              out.newLine();
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User Account '" + username + "'     Created");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
       }
```

the text file will looking something like this:

```
user1 password1
user2 password2
```

I have been reading through a lot of documentation to try and figure this one out however the more reading i do the more confused I get. The reason why I am doing it in this way is so that I can continue reading and writing to .dat files for the information that the system will eventually hold.

If anybody can help me in any way shape of form that would be amazing!

Thanks

C

Comment: Storing passwords in plain text is very bad practice.

Comment: I know, I wouldnt normally do it but I am making something that really doesnt need a password form but I want to learn the reading a line from a file...

Comment: If I select "George Washington" and "Father of His Country" as my user name and password respectively, what will your system do?

Comment: not allow login due to the spacing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and easy solution. Each line is commented but if you need any help or if there's anything you don't get please let know.

```
import java.io.*;
class FileRead 
{
 public static boolean main(String lineToCompare)
  {
  try{
  // Open the file that is the first 
  // command line parameter
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");

  // Get the object of DataInputStream
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

  String strLine;
  //Read File Line By Line

  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  //Compare the line with the line to compare (string)
  if(strLine.compareTo(lineToCompare) == 0)
      return true;
  }

  //Close the input stream
  in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
     System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }

  return false;

  }
}
```

Comment: Ok this makes much more sense!!! This would mean that i would have to combine both strings for the username and password into a string that is 'username password' and compare this new combined string with the lines inside of the text file right?

Comment: This is one way to do it. You could pass 2 strings in the function call and then when you read each line in the file you split it into 2 strings and compare them to the passed arguments. That is only if you don't accept spaces in username or password. Depends on what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure whether you want to execute the above code for a specific username and password, or all of them.

If you want to get specific line from the file, and you already have access to the offset of the line you want to read, you can use [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). This class lets you move the file pointer to a certain position, and then you can simply read the next line to get username and password.

However, if you want to read a specific line but have no information where that line could be in the input file, you will need to read each line (eg., using a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)) to find the one you need. You can also take this approach, if you want to read the files line by line.